# What is the best way to get the last word of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

if i have a string like:

```
var myString = "word1 word2";
var lastWord;
```

how can i make it so lastWord = "word2"?

Comment: `array=myString.split(); lastWord=array[array.length-1]`

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif although the first parameter for `split` is optional but it will return the string in an array, so it should be something like `split(' ')`

Comment: Yes you're right . for some reason can't edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression that matches the word characters (`\w+`) before the end of a string (`$`) might be a good fit here.

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array so just retrieve the first element.

```js
const str = 'word1 word2 word3';
const lastWord = str.match(/\w+$/)[0];
console.log(lastWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into an array based on the spaces, then get the last element

```js
const myString = "word1 word2";
const lastWord = myString.split(" ").at(-1);
console.log(lastWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with split() and pop():

```
const lastWord = myString.split(' ').pop();
```